# SignalR doesn't work with custom serializer

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, signalr

I'm trying to configure signalr to send JSON object with lower case members. Currently I'm configuring with a custom ContractResolver, and have put this in my startup code:

```
var serializer = new JsonNetSerializer(new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
});
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof (IJsonSerializer), () => serializer);
```

However, no javascript calls are received when it is configured like this. Any ideas what's wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok this helped me fix this issue:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/500#issuecomment-7453751